# Ruby Regular Expression for matching any subdomains and the top level domain

Tags: ruby, regex

I'm trying to create a regex that will optionally match any subdomains, and match the TLD. For example, it should match…

- https://example.com
- http://example.com
- https://test.example.com
- test.example.com
- example.com

It should not match…

- fakeexample.com
- https://fakeexample.com
- fake.fakeexample.com

I have this so far, which matches subdomains, but does not match when at the top level domain.
`(\A|(https?:\/\/))?(\w*|\S*)\.{1}example\.com`

Comment: Thanks, that worked!

Comment: This problem cannot be solved with a regex, because the *exact same* domain path may refer to a top-level domain or not, depending on the client's network. In particular, the domain paths you posted are all *relative*, not *absolute* paths, so they are looked up relative to the client's default suffix. For example, if I work for a company named "Foo" in Germany, which owns the domain `foo.de`, and it's communications department is using the domain `com` and has a server called `example`, then the DNS query for `example.com` will actually return the address of `example.com.foo.de.`.

Comment: What is wrong with the answer below?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may use

```
/\A(?:https?:\/\/)?(?:\S*\.)?example\.com\z/
```

See the [regex demo](http://rubular.com/r/JyO4hwW1vd)

**Details**

- `\A` - start of string
- `(?:https?:\/\/)?` - an optional (as the `?` quantifier at the end repeats 1 or 0 times) non-capturing group matching `http`, an optional `s` and then `//` substring
- `(?:\S*\.)?` - an optional non-capturing group matching 1 or 0 occurrences of 0 or more non-whitespace chars (with `\S*`) and then a dot (`\.`)
- `example\.com` - an `example.com` substring
- `\z` - end of string.